# Why does building an export in Next.js version 13.4.15 always produce a .txt file with the same name as the .html file?

Tags: next.js13

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/crTF9.png)
I am currently engaged in a web development project utilizing Next.js. As part of my build setup, I've configured a script in my package.json named 'npm run build'. Furthermore, my next.config.ts file is tailored with the output option set to 'export'. My query pertains to the resultant contents of the 'out' folder post the execution of this build process. A point of particular interest is whether it's typical or correct to find .txt files, each bearing the same name as a corresponding .html file, within this folder. This occurrence has been consistent in my build outputs, and I'm keen to understand if this is a standard behavior or an anomaly in the Next.js build process. In an effort to find an explanation, I have thoroughly examined the official Next.js documentation but have not found any content that specifically addresses this issue. Gaining clarity on this will significantly aid in streamlining and accurately managing the output of my project's build system

I have recently conducted an experiment by creating a basic, starter project in Next.js to further investigate the build process. After initiating a standard build of this minimal project, I observed that .txt files were generated alongside the .html files, just as in my main project. This occurrence in a simple, fresh project setup has led me to wonder about the consistency and correctness of this behavior in the Next.js framework. It seems to be a recurring phenomenon, not just limited to complex or customized configurations. I'm seeking to understand whether this is an intended feature or a potential issue within the Next.js build process, and how it impacts the overall file structure and deployment strategy.